# installing ubuntu on windows 10

Tags: dual-boot

I have bought a new laptop (acer notebook) with windows 10, but I can't install ubuntu 16.04 on it. When I make a bootable usb flash drive (by Rufus) and I put it in the flash drive, then pressing f12, the usb is not being recognized and the installation process doesn't start. 
Please help

Comment: Last time I tried Rufus, my USB key was not recognized. I don't remember which software I used this particular time but there are plenty.

Answer (score 0):

The boot selection key might be different. Mine will be a wild guess since I don't know the exact version of your computer. F8 and F9 (not simultaneously, but you can just mash them.) are the most preferred keys.

Make sure that the USB stick is connected to your PC. Restart it. While it's opening, start pressing F8 and F9. It should bring you a black/blue screen to choose a device from.

Select your USB stick and *DON'T* pull it until installation completely finishes and your computer restarts. After that it's safe to pull.

Enjoy your fresh install.

**Edit:** According to [this](https://www.desertcrystal.com/bootkeys) link for your pc it might be ALT + F2.

Comment: The boot key is F12, and I choose the device from it, but nothing happens. It seems that the system doesn't even recognize the usb boot drive which is imported and after choosing it, stops on a black page.